# Clone, Licensee from 1.0 or something else?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, piracy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Web applications inspired by Stack Exchange's system](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/web-applications-inspired-by-stack-exchanges-system)

I've noticed the [WireShark support](http://ask.wireshark.org/) site looks exactly like, *drumroll*, you guessed it: StackOverflow.

What's the deal with this?  Did they purchase a StackExchange 1.0 license and refuse to give it up?

Answer (score 2):

It is a clone - a codebase that mimics the SE format.

There are many of those around.

The link at the bottom of the page says that it is "Powered by OSQA" which links to the [OSQA](http://www.osqa.net/) site:

> OSQA is the free, open source Q&A system you've been waiting for. Your OSQA site is more than just an FAQ page, it is a full-featured Q&A community. Users earn points and badges for useful participation, and everyone in the community wins.

Comment: Hey, they still have double diamonds...

Comment: @casperOne - Getting diamond envy?

Comment: Perhaps.  I miss those days.  Maybe we can bring the star back while we're at it.